# process does not run when executing Java

Tags: java, process, command, exec

I am trying to run a .class file in java. Here's what I've tried:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("cd target/classes/; java -cp ./ SoundHandler Correct; cd ../../");
```

I did some googling and the best I could come up with was to tack this on to the end:

```
pr.getInputStream();
pr.getErrorStream();
pr.getOutputStream();
```

This did not help. I want to run a .class file in java. Thanks!

Comment: what is the issue ? it is not at all clear.

Comment: The .class file does not seem to run from when I execute the command from inside java.

Comment: and how can you say that ?

Comment: It does not play the sound or print "This is a test" (for debug). I know the command does not run because it does not play the sound I provided in the arguments. The command or the SoundHandler class itself does not raise any errors when I run the command from terminal in the same directory.

Comment: This question is not a dupe. I am simply cd to where the .class file is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving three commands to the runtime to execute - but only one parameter. It is trying to execute it as one command - however such a command does not exist.

If the command consists of multiple elements (command and arguments), they should be passed as a String array, so the runtime can differentiate them. If you are using shell commands, (like cd), then the command should be passed to the shell as a parameter.

Try something like this:

```
//if you are using unix-like OS. For Windows change sh -c to cmd /k
String[] cmd = new String[] {"sh", "-c", "cd target/classes/ && java -cp ./ SoundHandler Correct"};
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(cmd)
```

---

For debugging the process, you can read the command's output on the following way:

```
InputStream is = pr.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println("MSG: " + line);
}
```

---

A bit of update after some chat conversation: the main idea was working, but classpath needed some investigation.

Comment: What's the error/output you get?

Comment: None. It just continues with the main .class file.

Comment: There has to be something on the inputstream of the process.

Comment: I tried `pr.getOutputStream` and `pr.getErrorStream`, but nothing changes

Comment: Try to add an `echo success` to the start of end or the command (the last element of the cmd array). Also, note that you need to check the inputstream of the process, since this is the commands' output is written.

Comment: I did that, it did not output anything, even with `pr.getInputStream`.

Comment: How do you read the inputstream? At least a "success" message should be displayed.

Comment: `pr.getInputStream`. I obviously can't print it and understand it...

Comment: See my edit....

Comment: It turns out line = br.readLine() is null.

Comment: You put that code before or after executing the process? (Should be after)

Comment: I put it after..

Comment: I'm trying to start a chat, because it is going to take long otherwise. So just flooding this comment part and hoping that the option will pop up - don't know why the option is not more visible...

Comment: So adding a new comment... the chat option is still not available.

Comment: Well, let's add another one, I can feel that this will be lucky comment.

Comment: Apparently it was not, still no chat link.

Comment: Chat link chat link

Comment: Why there is no chat link

Comment: I can't chat. Not enough rep.

Comment: What? That needs also rep? Wow. I gave you all the rep I could.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180585/discussion-between-sushila-jyothi-leveque-and-skandigraun).